# Play music in background when home button is press

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer

I want to play music background and for this i made changes in info.plist . I set Applications does not run in background to *NO*, required background modes to *App plays audio*.

I added this in AppDelegate :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setDelegate:self];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];

}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSLog(@"Activating audio session");
    if (![audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDuckOthers error:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unable to set audio session category: %@", error);
    }
    BOOL result = [audioSession setActive:YES error:&error];
    if (!result) {
        NSLog(@"Error activating audio session: %@", error);
    }
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];

}
```

but music doesn't play anymore when i press home button. Any ideea please where i'am wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

and play audio on homeBtn screen on homeBtnEventMethod

1.) in **viewController.h** `#import <AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h>`

2.) `@property (nonatomic, strong) AVAudioPlayer *theAudio;`

3.) in **viewController.m** in viewDidLoad

```
 NSError *error = nil;
self.theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundURL error:&error];
```

4.) `- (IBAction)homeBtnTpd {
    [self.theAudio play];
}`

Answer (score 2):

You should set `Applications does not run in background` to NO

Comment: ok , i changed , but the same result. music stops when home is pressed

Comment: Did you  active `Audio Background Mode`?

Comment: In setting of project: `Capbabilities` > `Background mode`